# как написать код на питоне, в котором нужно задействовать метод перебора между всеми значениями трех одинаковых списков от 1 до 99

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
        x = list(range(1,100))
        y = list(range(1,100))
        z = list(range(1,100))
        t = 0
        j = 0
        q = 0

        def Ferma(i,j,q):
        for i in x:
            print(x[i],y[j],z[q])
            if x[i] == 99:
                j+=1
                print(x[i],y[j],z[q])
                Ferma(i,j,q)
                if y[j] == 99:
                    q+=1
                    print(x[i],y[j],z[q])
                    Ferma(i,j,q)
                    if z[q] == 99:
                        print(x[t],y[j],z[q])
                        Ferma(i,j,q)
                        print("END")


    Ferma(t,j,q)
```

этот код выдает только перебор между первыми двумя списками, притом перебор первого списка начинается с двойки, но третий список никак не перебирается

Answer (score 0):

Может, Вы хотите сделать это:

```py
def main():
    lists = [range(1, 100)] * 3

    for k in lists[0]:
        for i in lists[1]:
            for j in lists[2]:
                print(k, i, j)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***stdout (частично):***

```py
1 1 1
1 1 2
...
99 99 99
```